# ¿Cómo modifico la librería de spatie/laravel-permission?

Tags: laravel, permisos, users-roles, laravel-permission

Como haría para implementar el `spatie/laravel-permission` en un proyecto que ya tengo estructurado? Digamos que está casi terminado, solo necesito definir los permisos de los roles.

Ya tengo las tablas de rol, permiso, usuario, sus relaciones y sus columnas definidas, no tengo necesidad de correr la migración de la librería. Se que se puede cambiar como se llaman las tablas en la sección `'table_names' =>` de el archivo `config/permission.php`, pero cuando intento hacer algo de la librería, me pide columnas como `role_id` (que no tengo por que en mi caso se llama `rol_id`) y me da error.

¿No hay manera de modificar la libreria para que cambie las columnas que llama, como en el caso de los nombres de las tablas en el archivo `permission.php`?
Espero haberme explicado con claridad. Gracias de antemano

Adjunto `permission.php` para ejemplo + uno de los errores

```
<?php

return [

    'models' => [

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your permissions. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Permission" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Permission model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` contract.
         */

        'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your roles. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Role" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Role model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role` contract.
         */

        'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,

    ],

    'table_names' => [

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your roles. We have chosen a basic
         * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'roles' => 'roles',

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your permissions. We have chosen a basic
         * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'permissions' => 'permisos',

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'model_has_permissions' => 'usuario_permiso',

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models roles. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'model_has_roles' => 'usuario_rol',

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your roles permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'role_has_permissions' => 'rol_permiso',
    ],

    'column_names' => [

        /*
         * Change this if you want to name the related model primary key other than
         * `model_id`.
         *
         * For example, this would be nice if your primary keys are all UUIDs. In
         * that case, name this `model_uuid`.
         */

        'model_morph_key' => 'usuario_id',
    ],

    /*
     * When set to true, the required permission names are added to the exception
     * message. This could be considered an information leak in some contexts, so
     * the default setting is false here for optimum safety.
     */

    'display_permission_in_exception' => false,

    /*
     * When set to true, the required role names are added to the exception
     * message. This could be considered an information leak in some contexts, so
     * the default setting is false here for optimum safety.
     */

    'display_role_in_exception' => false,

    /*
     * By default wildcard permission lookups are disabled.
     */

    'enable_wildcard_permission' => false,

    'cache' => [

        /*
         * By default all permissions are cached for 24 hours to speed up performance.
         * When permissions or roles are updated the cache is flushed automatically.
         */

        'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),

        /*
         * The cache key used to store all permissions.
         */

        'key' => 'spatie.permission.cache',

        /*
         * When checking for a permission against a model by passing a Permission
         * instance to the check, this key determines what attribute on the
         * Permissions model is used to cache against.
         *
         * Ideally, this should match your preferred way of checking permissions, eg:
         * `$user->can('view-posts')` would be 'name'.
         */

        'model_key' => 'name',

        /*
         * You may optionally indicate a specific cache driver to use for permission and
         * role caching using any of the `store` drivers listed in the cache.php config
         * file. Using 'default' here means to use the `default` set in cache.php.
         */

        'store' => 'default',
    ],
];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [El código está bajo la licencia MIT](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/main/LICENSE.md), así que puedes hacerte un fork y modificarlo a tu gusto. Pero creo que te sería más fácil migrar los datos de tus tablas a las tablas de la librería.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responderme @porloscerrosΨ pero la cuestión es que no se como ni que archivos modificar de la librería, tienes bastante razón con lo de que seria mas fácil migrar mis datos a las tablas de la librería pero realmente quería mis migraciones 100% en español. Veré que solución encuentro, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te hace falta agregar esto a tu configuración:

```
'foreign_keys' => [

    /*
     * The name of the foreign key to the users table.
     */
    'users' => 'user_id',
],
```

También en el arreglo de `table_names`, deberás especificar que tabla es la que representa a tus usuarios.

```
'users' => 'tu_tabla_de_usuarios'
```

Comment: Gracias por responderme, pero tu código no ayudo en nada a mi problema...